# Specifying the subject line in an HTML email

Tags: html, email, html-email, subject

I'm coding a quick HTML email using [Foundation for Email](http://foundation.zurb.com/emails.html)s.
The tech stack isn't of huge importance, just highlights what I'm trying to accomplish in general.

Something I'm wondering about is when someone receives my email (through any of a huge number of possible email clients) is it possible for me to specify in my HTML template what the "Subject" line should read?

In case I'm not being clear enough, I'm referring to the teaser text you see in your inbox before opening the actual email:

Like in this instance from Gmail below: the "Your Amazon.com order of "Shovel Knight Amiibo"... text.

[image]

Is it possible to specify that text in my HTML template? Or is that handled by a service request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mail subject is a **header**, e.g:

```
From: John Smith <john.smith@example.com>
Subject: Good news!
```

It isn't taken from the message body so the answer is **no**.

You need to specify it with whatever program/code you use to actually deliver the message and it has to be plain text.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! Had a shockingly hard time trying to find this, everything I researched just pointed me to people trying to do this from a mailto link.

Comment: The thing is that email was invented like 20 years before HTML ;-)